# How to listen for preference changes within a PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment), I am subclassing PreferenceFragment and displaying it inside an Activity. That document explains how to listen for preference changes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening), but only if you subclass PreferenceActivity. Since I'm not doing that, how do I listen for preference changes?

I've tried implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my PreferenceFragment but it does not seem to work (`onSharedPreferenceChanged` never seems to get called).

This is my code so far:

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    public static final String KEY_PREF_EXERCISES = "pref_number_of_exercises";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        //IT NEVER GETS IN HERE!
        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_EXERCISES))
        {
            // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
            Preference exercisesPref = findPreference(key);
            exercisesPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="15"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="pref_number_of_exercises"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:title="Number of exercises" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Also, is the PreferenceFragment even the right place to listen for preference changes or should I do it within the Activity?

Comment: To your very last question it all depends on your Design framework. To use an MVC or MVP approach is hard to do with Android but I try to let all of my actions take place in the activity (Controller) hosting the fragment, and the fragment be the ui only (View/Presenter)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I believe you just need to register/unregister the `Listener` in your `PreferenceFragment` and it will work.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Depending on what you want to do you may not need to use a listener.  Changes to the preferences are committed to `SharedPreferences` automatically.

Comment: Ah, I see. That works. But should I be getting the SharedPreferences via `getPreferenceManager` (like you've done) or `getPreferenceScreen`? What's the difference?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what the real difference is, perhaps someone else can weigh in on it, it could be a good topic for another question as well.

Comment: Okay, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13618335/963396) is an answer to that question. It looks like there is absolutely no functional difference, but `getPreferenceManager` is generally the preferred option.

Comment: when the settings-preference is created for the first time, the summary is not set as per the stored preference value. How to resolve this??

Comment: @srv_sud inside your `onCreate()` call `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` directly

Comment: @Jose_GD : what instance of pref and let to pass in that method. Because in my onShardPrefChanged() I'll process the data before updation differently for different keys.

Comment: @srv_sud you mean what the `key` parameter should be? Haven't tried this, you have an example in Gunnar's answer below: `onSharedPreferenceChanged(null, "")`. It may not be suitable to your needs. Perhaps you should iterate on your keys of preferences that need an update

Comment: @Jose_GD: ya.. i think i need to iterate .. thanks for the answer.

Comment: why is unregistering necessary?

Answer (score 25):

The solution of antew works well, here you can see a full preference activity for Android v11 onwards:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class UserPreferencesV11 extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
            new PrefsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        // set texts correctly
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(null, "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // just update all
        ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_YOUR_KEY);
        lp.setSummary("dummy"); // required or will not update
        lp.setSummary(getString(R.string.pref_yourKey) + ": %s");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no this in a static class!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I absolutely have no clue which "this" you are referring to. The answer is 7 years old. Android has changed a lot.

Comment: public static class PrefsFragment declares a static class and then uses this inside to reference itself. But that is not possible, you can not use this within a static class.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the concept of static inner classes in Java? A static nested class may be instantiated without instantiating its outer class. Using 'this' is perfectly fine. This is not C#!

Comment: I am not sure, but I tried the code in Android Studio and it complains on the this: "        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);". I had to rewrite the code to get it to compile.

Answer (score 17):

All the other answers are correct. But I like this alternative better because you immediately have the Preference instance that caused the change.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Preference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.key_of_pref));        
    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            // do whatever you want with new value

            // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
            // in case you want to disallow the change return false
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Correct, although in `onSharedPreferenceChanged ()` you can access the Preference instance easily with `findPreference(key)`. Maybe the `SharedPreferences` way is preferred because of the registering/unregistering thing?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me from PreferenceFragment.onCreate()

```
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = 
    new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
    {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
        {
         showDialog();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it and avoid any potential memory leaks:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_movies);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences(); 

    //starts live change listener
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView () {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
//Unregisters listener here
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another complete example so you see the entire picture.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {


    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
            sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener =
            new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
                    String stringValue = value.toString();

                    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                        // the preference's 'entries' list.
                        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                        int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                        // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                        preference.setSummary(
                                index >= 0
                                        ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                        : null);

                    } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                        // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                        // using RingtoneManager.
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                            // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                            preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);
                        } else {
                            Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                                    preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
                            if (ringtone == null) {
                                // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                                preference.setSummary(null);
                            } else {
                                // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                                // name.
                                String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                                preference.setSummary(name);
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                        // simple string representation.
                        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GPSLocationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    ////////////////// NEW PREFERENCES ////////////////////////////

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GPSLocationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        Preference prefGPSServerAddr, prefGPSASDID, prefIsGPSSwitch;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_gps_location);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.

            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("gpsServer_Addr"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("gpsASD_ID"));


            prefGPSServerAddr = findPreference("gpsServer_Addr");
            prefGPSServerAddr.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                    try {
                        // do whatever you want with new value

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("Preferences", ex.getMessage());
                    }

                    // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
                    // in case you want to disallow the change return false
                    return true;
                }
            });

            prefGPSASDID = findPreference("gpsASD_ID");
            prefGPSASDID.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                    try {
                        // do whatever you want with new value

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("Preferences", ex.getMessage());
                    }

                    // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
                    // in case you want to disallow the change return false
                    return true;
                }
            });

            prefIsGPSSwitch = findPreference("isGPS_Switch");
            prefIsGPSSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                    try {
                        // do whatever you want with new value

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("Preferences", ex.getMessage());
                    }

                    // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
                    // in case you want to disallow the change return false
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
                if (tabletSize) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
                if (tabletSize) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
                if (tabletSize) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently finished putting together my own `PreferenceScreen` using the `Preferences API`, so I thought I would contribute my own full Example.. This includes updating the `Summary` to new/changed Value, as well as Listening for and reacting to changes.

**PS.** To answer your last question: To show a default Value for `Summary` upon initial creation of the `PreferenceScreen` (prior to any change in the Value), you *could* simply set the `android:summary` to a Value of your choosing, from within the `preferences.xml` file directly - and then, once there *is a change* in the Value, it will update automatically by using the code contained in my Example below. *Personally*, I use a short explanation of the `Preference` as my initial `Summary`, set within my `preferences.xml`, and then once the Value *does* get changed for the first time, it will simply show the current Value as the `Summary` from then on..

*Anyhow*, here is my full **Example:**

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public static final String PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE = "pref_notificationMode";
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;

@Override
public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    final SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());

    preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            if (key.equals(PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE)) {
                Preference notifModePref = findPreference(key);
                notifModePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

                //  DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE WHEN (PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE) IS CHANGED
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

    Preference notifModePref = findPreference(PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE);
    notifModePref.setSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getString(PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE, ""));

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

    super.onPause();
}
}
```

I hope this helps!
Any positive feedback is greatly appreciated, as I'm fairly new to StackOverflow ;)
**Happy coding!**

Comment: In `onPause`, should the `super.onPause()` be called before or after the listener is unregistered? Is there even a difference? I've seen both in numerous examples

Comment: @BryanWalsh I've also seen examples of _both_ ways.. I would think unregistering the listerner _before_ calling `super.onPause();` is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delare the specified Prefernce class in your `onResume()` method. In my case I was using `SwitchPreference` class, therefore the code would be like- **SettingsActivity.class**

```
public static class PrivacyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    public SwitchPreference switchPreference;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("privacy_notice_check");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_privacy);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
```

Then in the activity where you want to use the `PrefernceFragment` value, just use the `SharedPreference` object to call the values and trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the summary, using  [androidx preference library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) (see the [official guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)), and adding the following attribute in your layout xml will be enough:

```
<EditTextPreference
    ...
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution on Kotlin with PreferenceFragmentCompat

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat

Listen when prefChange

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        val prefListener =
            OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { prefs, key ->
                val valueChanged = preferenceManager.sharedPreferences.getString(key,key)
                when(valueChanged){
                    getString(R.string.value_lang_en) -> applyLang(valueChanged)
                    getString(R.string.value_lang_th) -> applyLang(valueChanged)
                }
            }
        preferenceManager.
        sharedPreferences.
        registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener)
    }
```