# PreferenceFragment - Difference between getPreferenceManager() and getPreferenceScreen()?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I've implemented my own PreferenceFragment subclass (detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596250/)), and want to listen for preference changes within it. PreferenceFragment provides you with two ways of doing this:

```
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Which one should be used? What's the difference? I don't really understand the [distinction made in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#getPreferenceManager%28%29).

Comment: From what I understand from the API, it seems that Screen is more specific and is not really guaranteed to be present whereas Manager should be available more often. +1 for a nice question!

Comment: Just to clarify regarding the renewed bounty, what is it you want to know beyond what Shruti and JoseLSegura have already answered.

Comment: Shruti's answer is largely copy/paste from the API docs, which I have already read several times. Jose's answer is more what I am looking for, but it does not seem authoritative enough. I'd simply like others to weigh in on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The core difference is in their names, `PreferenceManger` grants access to different functionalities to the developer for managing `SharedPreferences`, such as retrieving the map of current preference values or setting user preferences. to their default values. `PreferenceScreen` handles displaying a screen of user preferences, so that the user can assign values to them. Sometimes this means displaying a list item on a screen with other preferences, that opens another screen with more preferences when clicked, as is the case when `PreferenceScreen`s are nested.

Your question implies that you think there is a difference between what `PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences()` and `PreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences()` does, but according to the source code, they are identical.

`PreferenceScreen`:

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
     if (mPreferenceManager == null) {
         return null;
     }

     return mPreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences();
 }
```

So the `PreferenceManger` and `PreferenceScreen` are different entities, but the `SharedPreference` those method return should be the same object, since `PreferenceScreen` calls the method from `PreferenceManager`. I hope that is the answer you've been seeking.

If you have a choice, go with `PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences()`, it's more obvious and one fewer method call internally.

Fun fact:

`PreferenceFragment`:

```
public PreferenceManager getPreferenceManager() {
    return mPreferenceManager;
}

public PreferenceScreen getPreferenceScreen() {
    return mPreferenceManager.getPreferenceScreen();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely the answer I was looking for. I didn't even think to look at the Android source code.

Comment: Please share source code link or help about how to explore? In PreferenceScreen.java there is no method named getSharedPreferences(). I have explored  from below link. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/bd4cbab/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceScreen.java

Comment: find here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/bd4cbab/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.java

Answer (score 16):

The first one gets the shared preferences from the `PreferenceManager`. The second one, from the `PreferenceScreen`, that inherits this method from `Preference` class.

I think this is not a functional difference, because both return probably the same instance of the `SharedPreferences` objects, but I think it's clearer to use the first one (using `PreferenceManager` instead of `PreferenceScreen`).

Answer (score 13):

**PreferenceScreen** see domentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html)

> PreferenceScreen class can appear in two places:
>
> - When a PreferenceActivity points to this, it is used as the root and    is not shown (only the contained preferences are shown).
> - When it appears inside another preference hierarchy, it is shown and    serves as the gateway to another screen of preferences (either
>   by    showing another screen of preferences as a Dialog or via a
>   startActivity(android.content.Intent) from the getIntent()). The
>   children of this PreferenceScreen are NOT shown in the screen that
>   this PreferenceScreen is shown in. Instead, a separate screen will be
>   shown when this preference is clicked.

**PreferenceManager** see documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html).

**Difference** :

`getPreferenceManager ()` returns the current preference manager associated with the fragment.

`getPreferenceScreen ()` returns the root `PreferenceScreen` i.e. root preference screen used in the fragment from preference xml file(preferences.xml).