# Android: getPreferenceScreen vs getPreferenceManager

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I am little confused with the two methods available in **`PreferenceActivity`**, that are `getPreferenceScreen()` and `getPreferenceManager()`.

I have gone through the stackoverflow thread :

[PreferenceFragment - Difference between getPreferenceManager() and getPreferenceScreen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618335/preferencefragment-difference-between-getpreferencemanager-and-getpreference)

Which says that

`getPreferenceScreen()` : is related to screen and setting the values of xml and `getPreferenceManager()` : is related to preference management, i.e. getting the settings map and putting the values

But I am using the `getPreferenceManager()` and still can update **Preferences and its summary in xml**.

Can anyone please help me out to understand what is the key difference and what to use in what location?

Answer (score 1):

`getPreferenceScreen` is just a shortcut for `getPreferenceManager()`.`createPreferenceScreen()`.  Preference manager lets you override some other settings like what shared preference file to use.  If you need to use any of those functions, use `getPreferenceManager`.  If you don't, you can just use `getPreferenceScreen`