# How to listen for a preference change in a fragment?

Tags: android, listener

Lots of similar questions but I still can't find an answer.  So I have a Fragment where I want to listen for changes in a `PreferenceActivity`.

The documentation says to register the listener in `onResume()` and un-register in `onPause()`:

> *For proper lifecycle management in the activity, we recommend that you register and unregister your
>   SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener during the
>   onResume() and onPause() callbacks, respectively:*

I assume they are referring to registering the listener from within the `PreferenceActivity` `onResume/onPause` methods, since if you unregister the listener in the Fragment's `onPause()`, then it will not listen for the changes.

So is the solution to do the opposite i.e. - register in `onPause()` and un-register in `onResume()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, in the end I launched the preferenceactivity for result and responded to the preference changes in onActivityResult(). This was mainly because of something unusual I was doing in the PreferenceActivity, which was that when one preference changed, it has effect on 2 other preferences. So I am programmaticaly changing preferences in the preferenceactivity, and this caused the listener to trigger 3 times which I didn't want.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) that notify the changes on the preferences but the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) it's self. The [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) is a meare user interface to access the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

So if it's your fragment that needs to listen for [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) changes it should be the one to register for changes. In other words let your fragment implement the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) and register for this changes on the fragment `onResume` and unregister `onPause` as the doc say.

You also need to load the preference on the fragment `onResume` so when it goes `onPause` then `onResume` the current state of the preference is loaded.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596569/665823

Comment: OK thanks Kalem.  However i still don't understand your answer.  Here's why:  When i select the menu option "SETTINGS" my fragment is paused, and the settings window appears.  Therefore (if i do what you say above - unregister in onPause()) the fragment is no longer listening for changes, so what's the point?

Comment: For your usecase maybe there's no point. Just the `onresume` behaviour will do. Anyways if you register onpause your fragment won't receive the change event either cause it's inactive (correct me if am wrong).

Comment: Thanks again, in the end I launched the preference for result and responded to the preference changes in onActivityResult().  This was mainly because of something unusual I was doing in the PreferenceActivity, which was that when one preference changed, it has effect on 2 other preferences.  So I am programmaticaly changing preferences in the preferenceactivity, and this caused the listener to trigger 3 times which I didn't want.