# Setting a preference screen summary from switch preference state

Tags: android

Am trying to dynamically update a particular preference screen summary which nest sub options(This preference screen has it's own key name). My goal is that the preference screen summary should be updated by the state of a switch preference in it's sub or nested view. I tried using the guide here [How to listen for preference changes within a PreferenceFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596250/how-to-listen-for-preference-changes-within-a-preferencefragment) but this only shows how to dynamically update particular key references.

Any pointers to achieve this implementation for particular preference screen with key name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the newValue to a boolean and set summary as shown in code.

```
Preference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.key_of_pref));
PreferenceScreen parent = (PreferenceScreen) sf.findPreference("prefs_root");
pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
       boolean newValueBool = (Boolean) newValue;
       parent.setSummary(newValueBool ? "Summary is true" : "Summary is false");                                                  
       ((BaseAdapter) getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
       // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
       // in case you want to disallow the change return false
       return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my question. Sorry it not clear. My problem is updating a preference screen summary using the state of a switch preference and not updating the switch preference summary @Bojan

Comment: I have added some code. Use this code inside the **onPreferenceChange** listener

Comment: There is no instance of `Parent.setSummary()` inside the `onPreferenceChangeListener` @bojan

Comment: You need to make a variable outside and then use it inside. `PreferenceScreen parent = (PreferenceScreen) sf.findPreference("prefs_root");`