# How to Update a Fragment From PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android

My main activity has several fragments, one of which has a listview or gridview. I also have a preferenceActivity that configures how the app looks and functions, in particular whether to display the list or the grid.

When the list/grid view setting is changed in the preference activity I want to reflect that change in my fragment (located in my app's main activity). How do I do so from a separate activity? (in this cast from the preference activity).

**Edit**- I managed to accomplish this by using the onResume() callback to check if any relevant preference changed, and if there was a change:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean layout = settings.getBoolean("layout", false);
    if (layout == true) {
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: use onResume of the fragment to check the preference values

Comment: I hope this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596250/how-to-listen-for-preference-changes-within-a-preferencefragment

Answer (score 0):

You can start the `PreferenceActivity` by using the `startActivityForResult` which return the result in the MainActivity.In the onActivityForResult() update the view.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Update the view.
        }
}//onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a `interface` which listen the change action from preference activity and then main activity / fragment must implement interface above.